# Does Lean expose itself as a C/C++ or python library?

Tags: math, automation, computer-science, proof, lean

I am interested in doing a project relying on automated proofs, in great dimension as a learning exercise. So far my online search suggests Lean is the way to go, in theory.

However, all I read about it talks about using it as a proof assistant in VS code or Emacs. But that's not what I need, I need a system I can communicate with fully programmatically. I.E string of assumptions goes in -> string specifying deductibility comes out or something like that.

To be more precise, I need to be able to call parsing functions on strings that do the heavy work of determining whether a set of results is deducible from the input assumptions.

I cant find documentation about Lean being able to do this.

Comment: A quick search for "lean prover bindings" gave [this repository](https://github.com/dselsam/lean-python-bindings); please take a look to see whether it suits your needs.

Comment: It looks abandoned, it was last updated 3 years ago

Comment: @Makogan I wouldn't jump to conclusions; if Lean itself hasn't changed too much, maybe the Lean binding is still workable. My advice is to check out the project and see how much still works and go from there.

Comment: The current implementation of lean is version 3, version 4 is coming out soonish, version 4 is guaranteed to be incompatible with version 3. 

If that repo is not being maintained then even if it works today it won''t work some months in the future unfortunately.